# Find Max Slice Of Array | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find the maximum slice of the array which contains no more than two different numbers.

Here is my array `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]`

My thought process on this is to find the numbers that are not repeated and return their index within a new array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function goThroughInteger(number) {
    var array = [];
    //iterate the array and check if number is not repeated   
  number.filter(function (element, index, number) {
    if(element != number[index-1] && element != number[index+1]) {
        array.push(index);
      return element;
    }
  })

    console.log(array);
}
goThroughInteger([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]);
```

I'm unsure where to go next, I'm struggling to understand the question that being - find the maximum slice which contains no more than two different numbers - that confuses me.

Comment: Nice effort shown.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you

Comment: btw, filter without using the result of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) makes not really sense.

Comment: What should be the output in your example ?

Comment: The expected result is 10

Comment: @Filth What was wrong with NinaSholz answer ?

Comment: "Slice" usually refers to an array, not the number of elements. So are you looking for the maximum slice or the number of elements in the maximum slice?

Comment: It wasn't robust enough, it needs to handle any array such as [58, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 8988, 1, 1] which should return 4. Hers returned 2.

Comment: @Filth, and why does zero don't count?

Comment: The array example I used is equal to 10 as the array slice of (0, 9) is the largest slice of the array with no more than two different numbers. The same with the second array example which expected result is 4.

Comment: if 10 then 5 or 9 then 4.

Comment: We are after the output of the maximum slice of the array which contains no more than two different numbers.

Comment: please define *slice*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138016/discussion-between-filth-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with a single loop, which checks the last values and increments a counter.

```js
function getLongestSlice(array) {
    var count = 0,
        max = 0,
        temp = [];

    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var last = temp[temp.length - 1];

        if (temp.length < 2 || temp[0].value === a || temp[1].value === a) {
            ++count;
        } else {
            count = last.count + 1;
        }
        if (last && last.value === a) {
            last.count++;
        } else {
            temp.push({ value: a, count: 1 });
            temp = temp.slice(-2);
        }
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    });
    return max;
}

console.log(getLongestSlice([58, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 8988, 1, 1]));        //  4
console.log(getLongestSlice([58, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 356, 8988, 1, 1]));   //  5
console.log(getLongestSlice([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8])); // 10
```

Comment: Good, only solution so far with runtime complexity in O(n). Even lends itself nicely to generalization for slices of 3, 4 and more numbers.

Comment: Great solution! What this ```count = last.count + 1;``` means in Java Script? Especially the ```last.count```. I want to apply it in Swift.

Comment: @ChuckZHB, `last = temp[temp.length - 1]`. `last` is the last element of `temp`.

Comment: Should it add one more line ```temp[temp.length - 1].count = last.count``` to assign the last.count to last element of temp array's count property?
```if (last && last.value === a) {
            last.count++;
            temp[temp.length - 1].count = last.count
        }``` 
I think if not then ```last.count++``` is not reflect on the ```temp``` array. I try it on Swift as I'm not familiar with JS.

Comment: why? `last` contains the object reference to the last object, if exists.

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible solution, with complexity O(n²) (as pointed out by @le_m in the comments)

````js
goThroughInteger = (list) => {
  let scores = list.reduce((slices, num, pos) => {
let valid = [num];
let count = 0;
for (let i = pos; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (valid.indexOf(list[i]) == -1) {
    if (valid.length < 2) {
      valid.push(list[i]);
      count++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  } else {
    count++;
  }
}
slices[pos] = { pos, count };
return slices;
  }, []);

  scores.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
  let max = scores[0];
  return list.slice(max.pos, max.pos + max.count);
};

console.log(goThroughInteger([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]));
console.log(goThroughInteger([58, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 8988, 1, 1]));
```
````

The solution calculates the 'score' at every position of the input list, counting the length of a sequence of no more than 2 different values, then takes the result with the highest score and extracts a slice from the original list based on that information.

It can definitely be cleaned and optimized but I think it's a good starting point.

Comment: The worst-case runtime complexity of this solution is O(n²), not O(n). Consider the input `[1,1,1,...,1]` with n times the same element. Now, the inner for-loop never breaks and thus performs O(n) computations which, together with the outer reduce-loop, end up as O(n²).

Answer (score 3):

```
 function goThroughInteger(array) {  
   var solutionArray = [];
   var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
       for (var j = i + 1; j <= array.length; j++) {
         var currentSlice= array.slice(i,j);
         var uniqSet = [...new Set(currentSlice)];
      if(uniqSet.length <3) {
        if(currentSlice.length>max) {
        max= currentSlice.length;
        }
      }
     }      
  }
 console.log(max);
}

goThroughInteger([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]);
```

This solution checks every possible slice of the array, checks if it has not more than 2 different numbers and finally prints out the length of the longest slice.

Comment: This is perfect. Are you able to explain your thought process on this? I was struggling to understand the initial question.

Comment: The goal is to find the longest series of numbers which contains no more than two different numbers. 
The code generates every possible arrayslice (for loops) and generates a set of uniqe numbers of that array
(Set is an ES6 native object to store uniqe values and the '...' operator transforms the set back into an array).
If the length of that uniqe array is smaller than 3, the array is a valid solution candidate. 
Finally it checks if the length of the current arrayslice is bigger than the biggest length encountered so far and if so, stores it in max.

Comment: This solution requires `n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6` operations to compute max which corresponds to a runtime complexity of `O(n³)` - incredibly bad compared to the linear solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

## Using the sliding window algorithm in O(n) time:

```
const arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 8, 1, 1, 8, 8];

const map = {
   length: 0
};

let required = [];
for(start = 0, end = 0; end <= arr.length; ){

if(map.length > 2){
    if(map[arr[start]] === 1){
        delete map[arr[start]];
        map.length --;
    }else{
        map[arr[start]]--;
    };
    start++;

}else{
    if(end - start > required.length){
        required = arr.slice(start, end);
    };

    if(map[arr[end]]){
        map[arr[end]]++;
    }else{
        map[arr[end]] = 1;
        map.length++;
    }
    end++;
}
}

console.log(required);
```