# What does element.count & element.value means in array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I found a great solution to get maximum Bi-valued slice of an array. And I want to apply it in Swift. However, I'm not familiar with JavaScript, I search it via Google, but no result yet.

Well, I simply want to know what does `last.count` & `last.value` means in below code. What they do with element last?

```
function getLongestSlice(array) {
    var count = 0,
        max = 0,
        temp = [];

    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var last = temp[temp.length - 1];

        if (temp.length < 2 || temp[0].value === a || temp[1].value === a) {
            ++count;
        } else {
            count = last.count + 1;
        }
        if (last && last.value === a) {
            last.count++;
        } else {
            temp.push({ value: a, count: 1 });
            temp = temp.slice(-2);
        }
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    });
    return max;
}

console.log(getLongestSlice([58, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 8988, 1, 1]));        //  4
console.log(getLongestSlice([58, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 356, 8988, 1, 1]));   //  5
console.log(getLongestSlice([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8])); // 10
```

### Update:

Thanks. Now it is working in Swift.

```
import Foundation

struct Tmp {
    var value: Int
    var count: Int
}

func getLongestSlice(A: [Int]) -> Int {
    var count = 0,
        max = 0,
        temp: [Tmp] = []

    var last: Tmp = Tmp(value: 0, count: 0)

    for a in A {

        if temp.count != 0 {
            last = temp[temp.count - 1]
        }

        print("last: \(last)")

        if temp.count < 2 || temp[0].value == a || temp[1].value == a {
            count += 1
        } else {
            count = last.count + 1
        }

        if last.value == a {
            last.count += 1
            // assign last.count to last element's count of temp array
            temp[temp.count - 1].count = last.count
        } else {
            temp.append(Tmp(value: a, count: 1))
            temp = Array(temp.suffix(2))
        }

        if count > max {
            max = count
        }
     }
    return max
}

getLongestSlice(A: [58, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 8988, 1, 1]) // return 4
getLongestSlice(A: [58, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 356, 8988, 1, 1]) // return 5
getLongestSlice(A: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]) // return 10
getLongestSlice(A: [777]) // return 1
getLongestSlice(A: []) // return 0
```

From thread: [Find Max Slice Of Array | Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786186/find-max-slice-of-array-javascript)

Comment: `last` in this case is an object. thus, `value` and `count` is its params, calls with dot-notation

Comment: Thanks you! I'm understood now, this line ```temp.push({ value: a, count: 1 })``` puzzle me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `temp` array holds objects of the following shape:

```
{ count: ..., value: ... }
```

So the `last` refers to the last element of that array, while `count` and `value` are the properties of that element.

This is not related to JavaScript.

Comment: ok, could you tell me what ```count``` property do here, is that refer to the index of element ```last```?

Comment: The `count` property is a property of the object that gets created in the following line:
`temp.push({ value: a, count: 1 });`
The meaning of it is an algorithmic question not a JS related one.

Comment: Oh, I get it! Array ```temp``` here is stored some objects like ```[{value: a, count: 1}, {value: b, count: 5}]```. Before I think it is an Int array. So, the count could be meaning to times of occurrence for ```value``` in array.